# How to delete temp temporary internet files from internet explorer?

Tags: internet-explorer

Is there an easy way of deleting temporary files from internet explorer?

I'm doing silverlight development and when I run the .xap I often get the cached version of the files rather than the newly created one.  In IE, I've set the internet option: Check for newer versions of stored pages: to Everytime I visit the web page. But, this does not seem to work every time.

Comment: HAve you tried any Temp cleaner like  CCleaner or IE privacy Keeper ?

Comment: No I haven't tried ccleaner. Will look into it.

Comment: Try hitting CTRL+F5 to refresh. This should refresh and ignore the cached files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Internet Explorer Developer Tools has an option to always redownload from the server. `Tools / Developer Tools / Cache / Always Refresh from Server`.

Comment: This worked for me, and did what I wanted: set and forget. ... almost, if that setting would stick between IE restarts, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Which OS? The files are in your temp folder. Easy to find in Windows XP, trickier in Vista or W7.

Easiest way is probably to run [ccleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) (assuming Windows). It can do a fairly thorough system clean up, but can be told to only clear up temp files.

Answer (score 1):

While I would also recommend ccleaner, if you want to do it manually, the files are traditionally stored in (C:\Documents and Settings\username).  There will be a temporary folder that is hidden in here (use "show all files and folders" button).

Source: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20070918144719AAd4KPY

Comment: I also suggest best that I have seen two thumbs up for CCleaner!

Answer (score 1):

In IE any following instructions should be displayed on screen and easy to update window or another software.I always check for newer versions of stored pages and that will revert it back IE8

Answer (score 0):

On XP, at least, you can also do this directly from the Internet Properties dialogue (Tools -> Internet Options, or the Internet Options control panel).  The first tab has a "Delete Files..." button under the Temporary Internet Files section.